# Django query for string literal that starts with field value

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using Graphene with Django, and have a case where I need to retrieve the Django content type that corresponds to a class name with "Node" added, where something like this:

```
ContentType.objects.get(model__something="MyModelNode")
```

would retrieve a ContentType with "model" equal to "MyModel". If it were the other way around, I'd use "`model__istartswith='MyModel'`". In SQL I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE $1 ILIKE 'MyModel%';
```

but I don't see how to do that with a queryset. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "inject" the value with [**`.alias(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias) and then use the [**`__istartswith`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith) in the opposite order:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

ContentType.objects.alias(val=Value('MyModelNode')).filter(
    val__istartswith=F('model')
)
```

This will thus retrieve `ContenType`s with as `model`, the empty string `''`, `'M'`, `'My'`, etc.

That being said, if you just want to remove the last four characters, you use:

```
ContentType.objects.filter(val__istartswith='MyModelNode'[:-4])
```

this will construct a string with the last four characters removed, so `'MyModel'` instead of `'MyModelNode'`.

Comment: Thanks, alias is what I was missing. I considered removing the last four characters, but that's a bit fragile in case there is a class that has a suffix of a different length. I thought that searching for a substring would be more robust.